# JRE ignores TLSv1.1 preference

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start

I'm running Oracle's JRE version 1.8.0_291-b10 under macOS 11.4 and I'm unable to use a local JNLP which gets a JAR through TLSv1.1.

When running the JNLP using `javaws -wait ~/Downloads/test.jnlp` I'm getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS11 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12, SSL20Hello]` despite enabling all protocols in the control panel:
[image: TLSv1.1 enabled]

I also tried forcing the JVM (in case something's wrong with settings) by running `javaws -J-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1 -wait ~/Downloads/test.jnlp` but that gets me `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)`.

It seems like JRE cannot make TLSv1.1 connections no matter what. Is there any way to force it? Updating the application is out of question as this is a closed-source abandonware which normally requires IE6 & Windows XP to run.

Comment: *"Updating the application is out of question as this is a closed-source abandonware which normally requires IE6 & Windows XP to run."* - Seriously dude: get rid of of.  Surely you can find a replacement.

Comment: I'm crying a little every time I have to use it. Unfortunately it's an embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

You can find info [here](https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html). Its probably a little outdated, but contains necessary configuration. Summary:

1. Add `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1`
2. Create file enableTLS1.1.security with follows content (you can also copy that property from /jre/lib/security/java.security and remove TLSv1.1)

`jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves`

3. `-Djava.security.properties=<path to enableTLS1.1.security>`

Instead of 2) and 3) you can also remove TLSv1.1 from jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms properties within /jre/lib/security/java.security, but it is not good practice

Comment: *"... but it is not good practice"* - Because 1) TLSv1.1 is considered to be insecure and 2) by changing that setting in that way you are potentially affecting **all** java programs that use that JRE.  (Not just the specific application that is (?) hosted by a JNLP service that is out of date.)

Comment: The biggest irony of @StephenC 's comment: I *ONLY* need JNLP for outdated, ILO/iDRAC/etc. KVM services ;(